# How to link from one excel sheet to another using vlookup?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hyperlink, vlookup, spreadsheet

I have an excel workbook to track my online shop sales. There are two sheets: one for ‘Orders’ and the other for ‘Customers’. They are databases of my orders and clients, respectively. In the ‘Orders’ sheet one of the columns shows who the client is. I would like each customer in the ‘Orders’ sheet to link to the respective row of this customer in the ‘Customers’ sheet. Can I achieve this with VLOOKUP or something else?

Orders sheet

```
A             B          ...
Order number  Customer
1             A. Smith
2             B. Browns
3             P. Williams
```

Customers sheet

```
A              B           ...
Customer name  email
A. Smith       a@smith.com    
B. Browns      b@browns.com     
P. Williams    p@williams.com
```

I tried this, but won't work:

```
=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(B2;Customers!A:A;1;FALSE), B2)
```

Comment: Why hyperlink? just VLOOKUP(B2;Customers!A:A;1;FALSE) should work

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't link to the customer list. It just displays the name. I want to be able to click the name and it would redirect me to the customer on the other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Insert : link and have the names defined on the customer sheet (use Insert : Name : Define name to make your names - they do not accept spaces), then clicking on it will take you to the name on the other sheet.

[image]

I had "A Smith" typed in cell B12 on sheet2 and named it "A_Smith" which then works as a clickable link.